# What is the Real Scale of the Breath of the Wild Map?

Tags: the-legend-of-zelda, map, geography

I am questioning the world as it was built in the game *The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild*.

Consider the following map:

[image: Map of Hyrule]

Using the game's own paragliding system, [it's been calculated](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/6tx7ep/calculations_about_botws_map_size/) that the map has an area roughly equal to 84 sq km.

**Is this calculation correct?**

It only takes a few minutes to fly across the entire desert, and less than a half hour to cross the entire map on foot. However, the time scale is 60x faster than real life, so one would need to take this into consideration.

**For those unfamiliar with the game geography:**

1. There is a desert in the south-west corner, surrounded by mountains to the north and east. (all of the brown area in the bottom left is desert)
2. Elevations are depicted by lighter colors. The more white it is, the higher the elevation.
3. There is a huge volcano in the north-east, with large lakes of lava.
4. West of the volcano is a large forest/wooded area, surrounded by water on all sides.
5. There is a large butterfly-shaped lake in the southern center of the map with a bridge going across. This bridge only takes a few minutes to cross in the game in real-world time.

**Good answers will give estimates based on real calculations, explaining how answers were arrived at.**

Comment: "_However, the time scale is 60x faster than real life, so one would need to take this into consideration._" How specifically?  Shouldn't you be able to ignore that completely, since we are only concerned about distances and not speeds?

Comment: @JMac If we're determining the "real" scale of the map, then the travel times are important in deciding if the distances you calculate are reasonable or not.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, open world games have far smaller maps than is physically realistic. For example, in *Skyrim*, Whiterun has about 20 houses and a similar number of residents, but is allegedly a large-ish city. You can find similar discrepancies in BotW itself (e.g. Gerudo Town is not a "town" by any reasonable standard). The usual interpretation is that the "real" version is bigger, but was shrunk due to [technical limitations](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LiteraryAgentHypothesis).

Comment: @overlord If you want to put importance onto travel times, you have to put the same importance onto Link's movements and size.  If you take into account how quickly time travels, you just get a lot of weird irrelevant details, like that we can watch Link's limbs move incredibly slow in "real time"; so obviously we wouldn't be able to use Link's motion as any type of traditional measurement for distances, since when time is factored in, Link doesn't move like a regular person.  You're better off to just use lengths and ignore how time passes; because it has a lot of weird consequences.

Comment: @JMac because one way of measuring distance is how long it takes to cover

Comment: @OrangeDog But in this game, the relative time of things does not match up with their expected scale in our world.  If the time scale is 60 x faster than regular life, then you can watch Link's movements in game and clearly see he doesn't move 60x faster than a regular person, so trying to gauge distance by how long it takes to cover things doesn't make much sense, because the speed Link moves at will not be a standard human moving speed, it's ~60x slower.  If you account for time moving faster, you have to account for Link moving slower, and those basically cancel.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know it’s been a while since this thread was started, but I have something to add. I am actually the author of that Reddit post you linked. (I’m glad you found it interesting.) Since then, we've come a long way— and actually have a definitive answer. Through datamining, there is the extremely helpful [BotW Object Map](https://objmap.zeldamods.org). It’s mostly used for the locations of in-game items, but recently I noticed there is a measuring feature that uses the in-game meters system, much as I did. If you turn on the field map
areas (the areas the game internally uses to control the weather among other things) you can see the boundaries of where Link can explore. Using the measure feature we find Hyrule is a rather neat 8 km by 10 km, or 80 sq. km— which fits my original estimate of between 72 and 86! So Hyrule isn't very large in real world terms, but the developers certainly did a good job at making it seem so.

I also want to add that they definitely did take the sped-up time scale into account in the game— just possibly not accurately. When you obtain all the memories, Impa says Kakariko Village is about three days from the Blatchery Plain, which obviously means in-game and not in real life. The Object Map tells us that the distance, following the path, is about 2.25 km. I’m not sure if she meant by horse or by foot though, so something to test in the game is how long it would take! To answer the general question of time, I guess it depends whether you assume days in Hyrule are just much shorter than in real life, or if it narratively is supposed to be equivalent regardless of actual activity. That could change the narrative effect of Link being asleep for 100 years— if it’s in Hyrulean time, that’s only 1.667 years in real life!

Comment: It 100 years was indeed in Hyrulean time then it is possible that soon there will exist save games where link spent more time lollygagging around the world than asleep

Comment: Impa actually says "half a day". If she means half a daytime, which in botw is huge (day breaks at 5, night starts at 9) then that's 8h to cover 2.25km. She definitely means walking (maybe backflipping?)

Answer (score 6):

84 square kilometers is roughly 9.16km to a side (5.6mi). Eyeballing the map, this seems reasonable.

However, the average walking speed of a human is about 5km/hr, which means you *should* be able to cross the map in about 2 minutes Real Time. If it takes about one day/night cycle in-game to cross the map, this would imply that the map is 120 kilometers across (or ~75 miles). This makes for a total map size of 14,400 square kilometers

If I had to guess, I'd say the map is indeed closer to 85km<sup>2</sup>, but that Time is not set to reflect this in terms of movement speed.

Comment: Did you mean 2 minutes there? Or hours?

Comment: I'd also say that the day/night cycle is probably the most inaccurate part of this calculation, purely because the speed of everything else doesn't match up with the day/night cycle speed. It is unrealistically fast compared to everything else to be considered any kind of accurate measurement of time.

Comment: Yeah, I think the assumption that Link's walking speed is 5 km/hr can be easily dismissed here, because if you assume that, the scale of all the objects and people in game would become _way_ different than what we expect in real life.

Comment: Trying to relate walking time with in-game hours doesn't make sense. As with every open-world game with an accelerated time schedule, movement occurs at real-time speed, not in-game time speed.

Answer (score 0):

You said that link can cross the map in half an hour. The average jog speed is 8.3 miles an hour. So 4.15 miles for half an hour. Which means at 60 times speed the map is roughly 250 miles across. If you use average walking speed the map is 90 miles and it is roughly 480 miles if you use sprinting speed.

Of course this is only using his movement speed as a measurement.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The point of the question is to reconcile the different estimates of the size, hopefully with reference to some canonical measure.  I'm not sure this helps that much.

Comment: You cannot measure the size of a map using in-game time to calculate speed. Movement in the game obvious occurs at real-time speed, not in-game-time speed.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
On the land of Hyrule, players can reach almost all of Hyrule except for the western and northern edges of the map. This area is 10km by 8km, so technically The Legend of Zelda: The breath of the Wild's map is 10km by 8km.

In addition to the playable map, there is a ring of external terrain around the map. The entire external terrain contains dimensions of 16km by 16km. This is the maximum map size that this terrain system can represent in Breath of the Wild.

[image: zelda02_far_landscape]

There is a ring of distant mountains outside the external landscape, mainly on the west and north sides of the map, whose farthest point from the map center is more than 20km, and the mountains in the southwest corner are about 43km away from the mountains in the northeast.

[image: zelda03_far_moutains]

The largest object on Hyrule, except the sky box, is the distant sea, which is 55 km in diameter.

See [the TAColor article 'What is the Real Scale of the Breath of the Wild Map'](https://www.tacolor.xyz/The_size_of_the_Breath_of_the_Wild_Map.html).

Comment: Are the various figures given in your answer derived from an official source? If so, you could greatly improve your answer by [edit]ing it to specify that source.